# Does AnyChart for android or SciChart support not ascending x-axis?

Tags: android, android-studio, anychart, scichart

I need to build an app that draws a line graph from data that is sent to the phone over bluetooth in real time. Data that I get should draw a graph similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMNoO.jpg). I tried with MPandroid charts but it's not working because is not supported I checked and GraphView doesn't support unsorted x-axis line graphs either. Does anybody know if SciChart or AnyCharts support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the AnyChart Android library supports unsorted xScale and real-time update of the chart. If you need any sample based on AnyChart, please, contact us support@anychart.com

Comment: I used AnyChart scatter chart as you advised me. It works great. Thank you for the help and the fast replay to my e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely Scichart supports data not ascending in X.

If you append data to a SciChart Android DataSeries you will see the following warning:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data has been changed to a
>   DataSeries which is unsorted in the X-Direction. Unsorted data can
>   have severe performance implications in SciChart.

This warning is intended to prevent you from accidentally appending data to a series that is unsorted (which results in poorer performance). If you intended to do this, then simply set [DataSeries.setAcceptsUnsortedData(true)](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/SciChart.Charting~com.scichart.charting.model.dataSeries.DataSeries~setAcceptsUnsortedData.html). Now append away!

There are several axis types in SciChart. In MPAndroidChart you only get a category axis (data is measured in X based on x-index). In SciChart you can get a category axis or a value axis (which measures data based on X-value).

To read more about the different axis types in SciChart, please see this article: [Axis Types in SciChart Android](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/Axis%20Types.html)